# "Error in: Length of logical index vector" when creating ggvis stack bar chart with Shiny & DT DataTable

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, ggvis, dt

I am trying to build a shiny dashboard which has a chart and a HTML5 DataTable from DT Package below the chart. The chart is connected to the DataTable such that filtering the DataTable will filter the chart.

I am able to successfully bring this functionality for a ggvis scatter plot but when I try to do the same for a bar plot I get the error `Error in: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 10, got: 0`

Here is the `server.R` for the scatter plot which works

```
server <- function(input, output) { 


  server_DF <- data.frame(dataset)


  output$html_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(unique(server_DF[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]),
                  filter = "top", selection = "multiple")
  })



  filtered_rows <- reactive({
    input$html_data_table_rows_all
  })



  vis <- reactive({
        # filtered_rows <- input$html_data_table_rows_all

        xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
        yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
        colvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$colvar))                                   


        p <- server_DF[filtered_rows(),] %>%
        ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar, fill := colvar) %>%
        layer_points() %>%
        set_options(width = "auto", height = "auto", resizable=FALSE)

        p


          })



  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot", "ggvis_ui")


}
```

Here is the code for the bar plot that gives me the error. Note that the only thing different is the `layer_bars()` which was `layer_points()` in the above code.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 


  server_DF <- data.frame(dataset)


  output$html_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(unique(server_DF[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]),
                  filter = "top", selection = "multiple")
  })



  filtered_rows <- reactive({
    input$html_data_table_rows_all
  })



  vis <- reactive({
        # filtered_rows <- input$html_data_table_rows_all

        xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
        yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
        colvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$colvar))                                   


        p <- server_DF[filtered_rows(),] %>%
        ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar, fill := colvar) %>%
        layer_bars() %>%
        set_options(width = "auto", height = "auto", resizable=FALSE)

        p


          })



  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot", "ggvis_ui")

}
```

Found that if I remove the `fill := colvar` it produces the histogram. But when I put in the `fill := colvar` like I did for the scatter plot I get an error.

Here is the complete code with `ui.R` and the sample data for the scatter plot. Just want to replicate the below for the stacked bar.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggvis)
library(DT)


data("diamonds")

dataset <- diamonds
rm(diamonds)

axis_vars <- names(dataset)

ui <- fluidPage(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Sample Dashboard"),

  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput('xvar', 'X Axis', axis_vars, selected = axis_vars[2]),
    selectInput('yvar', 'Y Axis', axis_vars, selected = axis_vars[7]),
    selectInput("colvar", "Colour", axis_vars, selected = axis_vars[4])

  ),

  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      ggvisOutput("plot")
    ),

    fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Select Columns To Display',
                              names(dataset),selected = names(dataset))
           ),
    column(width = 8,
           div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', DT::dataTableOutput('html_data_table'))
           )

    )

  )
))


server <- function(input, output) { 


  server_DF <- data.frame(dataset)


  output$html_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(unique(server_DF[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]),
                  filter = "top", selection = "multiple")
  })



  filtered_rows <- reactive({
    input$html_data_table_rows_all
  })



  vis <- reactive({
    # filtered_rows <- input$html_data_table_rows_all

    xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
    yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
    colvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$colvar))                                   


    p <- server_DF[filtered_rows(),] %>%
      ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar, fill = colvar) %>%
      layer_points()

    p


  })



  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Been struggling with this for a couple of days. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `input$html_data_table_rows_all` is `NULL` at the start. So you need to keep a condition to run that reactive code only when it is not `NULL`. I have modified your server code to do exactly that.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 

  server_DF <- data.frame(dataset)

  output$html_data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(unique(server_DF[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]),
                  filter = "top", selection = "multiple")
  })


  filtered_rows <- reactive({
    input$html_data_table_rows_all
  })

  observe({

    #Check that the input for the plot is not NULL
    if(!is.null(input$html_data_table_rows_all)){

      vis <- reactive({
        # filtered_rows <- input$html_data_table_rows_all
        xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
        yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
        colvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$colvar))                                   

        p <- server_DF[filtered_rows(),] %>%
          ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar, fill = colvar) %>%
          layer_bars()
        p

      })

      vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
    }
  })
}
```

Hope it helps!